# Change every character in a cell with another in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large list of phrases that I would like to make more disguised.  I want to substitute each letter/character with another character and be able to decode this with another formula so I am able to answer my own scrambles.

The problem I am having with the substitute function is that it changes each letter one by one instead of all at once.  Here is an example of what happens:

I want to change `abcxyz` with the following substitution code:

- a=z
- b=y
- c=x
- x=d
- y=e
- z=f

What happens is this text:

```
fedxba
```

Gets converted to this:

```
zyxdef
```

And then I will be abled to convert it back to this:

```
abcxyz
```

I hope this makes sense, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: The `tr` command in Linux is designed to do this kind of job if you are interested.

Comment: [so] dulicate: [Implementing a simple substitution cipher using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22049805)

Comment: Search for "simple substitution cipher excel" to get some more hints.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not sure I understand some of these comments, e.g. to "Linux", "VBA" and "script writing". The OP has clearly tagged microsoft-excel and worksheet-function.

Comment: @mgdo How many characters are we talking about? A maximum of 6, as in your example? Or potentially more? How many more?

Comment: These are anywhere from 12 to 25 characters per cell that I am looking to change. VBA does seem to get the job done, but I am certainly trying to use excel to solve this. I have tried a number of things already. I have tried SUBSTITUE function within multiple SUBSTITUTE functions. I have tried a REPLACE function and a new formula 26 times to see if that would work. Just looking for some help as far as the best formula or combination of formulas to use or if I must use another program.

Comment: If you want to do this with excel formulas, you will need a formula for each letter in the original word.  For decoding, you'll either need to extend your substitution table, or refer to a different table with the reverse coding (or using Index/match instead of vlookup to find the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, if you want to do this using only worksheet functions, you will need to have a separate formula for each character in the original word.
You will also need a Substitution table.

Here is one method.  I have NAME'd the substitution table `SubTable`.  The original word is in `A2`.  I have only copied the formulas down 9 rows, but if you might have 25 characters in a word, you will need to fill down that many rows.  The "coded" word will be at the bottom.

To encode:

```
A3:  =IFERROR(REPLACE($A2,ROWS($1:1),1,VLOOKUP(MID($A2,ROWS($1:1),1),SubTable,2,0)),$A2)
```

To decode:

```
B3:  =IFERROR(REPLACE($B2,ROWS($1:1),1,INDEX(SubTable,MATCH(MID($B2,ROWS($1:1),1),SubTable[Sub],0),1)),$B2)
```

[image]